# Conv1D: ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_1 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 2)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am inputting data with dimensions (2363,2) in a Conv1D Model. The input_shape I'm specifying in the input layer is (202,2). Here's the CNN part of the model:

```
model_2 = Sequential()

model_2.add(Conv1D(256, kernel_size=1, activation='relu', input_shape=(202,2)))
model_2.add(BatchNormalization())
model_2.add(MaxPooling1D())

model_2.add(Conv1D(128, kernel_size=1, activation='relu'))
model_2.add(BatchNormalization())
model_2.add(MaxPooling1D())

model_2.add(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=1, activation='relu'))
model_2.add(BatchNormalization())
model_2.add(MaxPooling1D())

model_2.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=1, activation='relu'))
model_2.add(BatchNormalization())
model_2.add(MaxPooling1D())

model_2.add(Flatten())

model_2.add(Dense(4,kernel_initializer="uniform",activation='relu'))
model_2.add(Dense(1,kernel_initializer="uniform",activation='softmax'))
```

The error I'm getting while executing the code:

```
 ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_1 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 2)
```

I'm pretty sure this is an issue of input shape and dimensions but as I am new to CNN, can someone help me correct this? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your problem
You have to reshape your training data
You can use numpy to do this,

```
 x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (-1,202,2))
```

Comment: Thanks but it isn't working...Getting the same error...there's an issue with the input shape. Any other solutions?

Comment: @SparshGupta I found your problem and edited my answer, check it out

Comment: @MushfiratMohaimin....after incorporating this, I'm getting the following error- ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 4726 into shape (202,2)

Comment: @SparshGupta what is the shape you had before?

Comment: Hey @MushfiratMohaimin, I reshaped the data to (2363,2,-1) because I was facing another error while using (-1,2363,2).....Now, I'm getting the following error- ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 2 but received input with shape (None, 2, 1)

Comment: @SparshGupta Which error did you face because of shaping to (-1,2363,2)? And what was the code? Start another question on it, as it's another question.

Comment: The error I faced was that the training data was only left with 1 sample. So, I wasn't able to split it into validation data while fitting the model.

Comment: If you have only 1 sample in your training data, then it means it has only one class to train on. This does not make any sense

Comment: It happened because I shaped the data to (-1,2363,2).....when I reshaped it to (2363,2,-1)...I got 2363 samples..After getting 2363 samples, now I'm facing this error:ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 2 but received input with shape (None, 2, 1)

Comment: @SparshGupta what is the shape of a sample? is it (202,2) or (2363,2)?

Comment: After reshaping it to (2363,2,-1), the shape of the training data has now become (2363,2,1)..so the shape of a single sample has now become (2,1), and the no. of samples are 2363....which is the correct shape that I want to now input into the input layer

Comment: the first shape should represent the number of samples, and the rest should represent the shape of a single sample. If you have 2000 samples, and each sample has shape (2,3), then the data must have a shape of (2000,2,3)

Comment: Yeah, so the current data shape is (2363,2,1) and the each sample shape is (2,1)

Comment: @SparshGupta then change the input shape of your model to (2,1) and try training. This should solve the problem

Comment: I have asked a new question with some editing. The input_shape which I am now giving on the input layer is (2,1). There is some other error now. Can you now please look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68372530/valueerror-negative-dimension-size-caused-by-subtracting-2-from-1-for-maxpool1d