# ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for MaxPool1D with input shapes: [?,1,1,128]. Full code,output & error in the post:

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have an error while making the following CNN model:

```
features_train = np.reshape(features_train, (2363,2,-1))
features_test = np.reshape(features_test, (591,2,-1))
features_train = np.array(features_train)
features_test = np.array(features_test)

print('Data Shape:', features_train.shape, features_test.shape)
print('Training & Testing Data:', features_train, features_test)

model_2 = Sequential()

model_2.add(Conv1D(256, kernel_size=1, activation='relu', input_shape=(2,1)))
model_2.add(BatchNormalization())
model_2.add(MaxPooling1D())

model_2.add(Conv1D(128, kernel_size=1, activation='relu'))
model_2.add(BatchNormalization())
model_2.add(MaxPooling1D())

model_2.add(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=1, activation='relu'))
model_2.add(BatchNormalization())
model_2.add(MaxPooling1D())

model_2.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=1, activation='relu'))
model_2.add(BatchNormalization())
model_2.add(MaxPooling1D())

model_2.add(Flatten())

model_2.add(Dense(4,kernel_initializer="uniform",activation='relu'))
model_2.add(Dense(1,kernel_initializer="uniform",activation='softmax'))
```

The output and the error while executing:

```
Data Shape: (2363, 2, 1) (591, 2, 1)

Training & Testing Data:
[[[0.5000063 ]
  [0.4999937 ]]

 [[0.5000012 ]
  [0.4999988 ]]

 [[0.50005335]
  [0.49994668]]

 ...

 [[0.50000364]
  [0.49999636]]

 [[0.5000013 ]
  [0.49999866]]

 [[0.49999487]
  [0.5000052 ]]] 

[[[0.50000024]
  [0.4999998 ]]

 [[0.5000017 ]
  [0.49999833]]

 [[0.50003964]
  [0.49996033]]

 ...

 [[0.5000441 ]
  [0.4999559 ]]

 [[0.5       ]
  [0.5       ]]

 [[0.5000544 ]
  [0.4999456 ]]]
```

```
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for '{{node max_pooling1d_1/MaxPool}} = MaxPool[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", explicit_paddings=[], ksize=[1, 2, 1, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 2, 1, 1]](max_pooling1d_1/ExpandDims)' with input shapes: [?,1,1,128].
```

The data I'm trying to input is features_train which has the shape (2363,2,1). I believe this is some issue with input_shape and dimensions. I'm new to neural networks, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your input shape is (2,1). What do you expect to get after several maxpooling layers and convolution layers? Hint: Each maxpool layer downsize input by 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MaxPooling1D` downsizes the model by 2, so the output of the first Pooling Layer is 1, then you have more Pooling layers which won't work, as it cannot be downsized by 2 anymore
Therefore, you cannot have more than 1 Pooling Layer in your model
Also, I would not suggest to use a `MaxPooling1D` layers on such a small input
Another thing, You have 1 unit on the final layer and a *softmax* activation function which makes no sense. Using *softmax* on the final layer with one unit will always return a value of 1
So, I think you want to use *sigmoid* and not *softmax*
Your model should be like this,

```
model_2 = Sequential()

model_2.add(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=1, activation='relu', input_shape=(2,1)))
model_2.add(BatchNormalization())

model_2.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=1, activation='relu'))
model_2.add(BatchNormalization())

model_2.add(Flatten())

model_2.add(Dense(10,kernel_initializer="uniform",activation='relu'))
model_2.add(Dense(1,kernel_initializer="uniform",activation='sigmoid'))
```